# Hibernate: Connect to MySQL without Username or Password

Tags: mysql, hibernate, connection-string, database-connection

I am developing a hibernate application that connects to a MySQL database.

The customers would like to only specify a connection string, ie:

```
jdbc:mysql://username:passwd@server:port/db_name
```

However, Hibernate will not connect using just this string. It also wants the username and password connection properties set. Is there any way around this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hibernate itself does not "want username and password connection properties set"; it just passes them to your JDBC driver. Depending on what [database connection pool](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-hibernatejdbc) you're using user / password may be specified via different methods.

MySQL JDBC driver allows you to [specify username / password in the URL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html), but not in the format you've shown in your question. They should be specified as parameters instead:

```
jdbc:mysql://server:port/db_name?user=username&password=passwd
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That worked. As a note if anyone wants to use the string in XML they need to replace the & with &amp;